# Unable to Fix brightness in DELL N5110?

Tags: dell

want to control the brightness (which is by default set to 100%). I want to lower it down because its killing my battery life and drains it out in matters of seconds. I cannot control the brightness using fn keys and other control provided in backtrack 5 o/s.

Information:

- Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS Release: 10.04 Codename: lucid
- Model Inspiron N5110
- kernel Linux bt 2.6.39.4

`lsmod | grep dell`:

```
dell_rbu                5691  0 
dell_wmi                1413  0 
sparse_keymap           3194  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop             7700  0 
wmi                     8772  1 dell_wmi
dcdbas                  5557  1 dell_laptop
rfkill                 14987  3 dell_laptop,cfg80211,bluetooth
```

Answer (score 1):

switch to latest release 11.10
I am using it no problems so far all Fn keys brightess touch pad volume are working a ok.

I own Dell N5110 and using it as my primary machine with ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
lsmod | grep dell
```

Do you see "dell-laptop" and "dell-wmi" there?

If not, try to modprobe them:

```
sudo modprobe dell-laptop dell-wmi
```

Comment: ok let me past the output

Comment: Hmm, what kind of graphics card do you have?  `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 0df5 (rev a1)